# Hyperlink and passing variables across pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, hyperlink

I want to pass an int as the user navigates across the pages.

I have got this:

```
Hyperlink q = new HyperLink();
q.Text = ThreadName;
q.NavigateUrl = "AnswerQuestion.aspx";
```

Lets suppose that i want to pass the number 5 to the other page. How do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Default : Page
{
    q.NavigateUrl = "AnswerQuestion.aspx?x=5";
}

class AnswerQuestion : Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);

        string x = this.Request.QueryString["x"];
        int i;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(x, out i))
            throw new Exception("Can't parse x as int");

        // then use i
    }
}
```

---

You can secure such operation. Use LinkButton instead of HyperLink on first page:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Question.aspx?x=5">Question #5</asp:LinkButton>
```

and then on second:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default.aspx" %>

if (this.PreviousPage != null && this.PreviousPage.IsValid)
{
    // do the same
}
```

Note that PreviousPage property is strongly typed, i.e. is type of Default not just Page

Comment: oooh nice.. you put it in the url..I forgot that u can do that!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Session variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) to set a value on one page:

```
class Default : Page
{
    // ...other code

    Session["myValue"] = "5";
}
```

And then pick it up on the receiver page with:

```
class TargetPage : Page
{
    // other code...
    int x; 
    try {
        x = int.Parse(Session["myValue"]);
    } catch {}

    // do something with x
}
```

The good thing about `Session` variables is that you can use any data type/object, and it's hidden from the user, i.e. not visible in the URL.